# Do all double displacement reactions lead to precipitates?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation

I know that most of the double displacement reactions form some kind of precipitates as their products. But do all of the double displacement reactions form precipitates? I have searched on this site as well as on Google, I've found answers, but they are not clarifying my doubts. Maybe I need a simpler explanation.

So, if you answer is yes, they all lead to precipitation, please justify.

If it's no, not all of them give precipitates, please justify with an example.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/how-can-you-predict-a-double-displacement-reaction-with-no-precipitate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, recall the definition of a precipitate "insoluble ionic compound". Take this reaction into consideration $$\ce{ NaOH~(s) + HCl~(l) <=> H2O~(l) + NaCl~(aq)}$$ none of the products are insoluble. You'll learn more when you go over gas evolution reactions.

Comment: @MARamezani Please use `<=>` in mhchem ;) Subscripting the state is also not encouraged any more.

Comment: The exception cited above is a neutralization reaction, a special type of double replacement reaction